# Automatic Send E-mail PHP After Several Months

Tags: php, email

I am creating a system that could send and e-mail to client when their payment need to pay. I have a DB that contain their status. If their status is 10 month, it will send an alert email to my client. I know the function of mail() but how to do this function work after 10 month of last my client payment?

Comment: This has nothing to do with email and everything to do with scheduling a task. You should use cron for that, which itself is technically unrelated to PHP (although you will commonly run a PHP script with cron)

Comment: Never learn that, but I will note that and google it. Is it possible to create the function every time I open my application?

Comment: That might be a bit excessive, or unreliable. What happens if nobody happens to open the application for a year?

Comment: Well, You right... But is there any idea except cron? I've read it at wiki, and I don't understand how to use that. If there's no any idea, maybe I will create as my logic... and I need to open it everyday :(

Comment: Cron is really easy. Most hosts even have an interface to do all the hard work for you.

Comment: Okay... Noted it... For now I'm using Burhan method... After I learn cron I will use that. Thank You

Comment: is there any create_date,subscription_start_date or subscription_end_date in your table give important fields in your table to give answer cron job on good programs with optimized queries in these cases will work better

Comment: @SivagopalManpragada You mean I need to push cron to DB? The subscription is not same for any client, even sometimes 1 client can pay after 2 years inactive (not paying for first year, then pay again after 2 years inactive, then the billing cycle begin again)

Comment: @user3608809 SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), STR_TO_DATE(date_subscription) > status_in_days; this kind of query will return you the ending subscriptions put the code in php file and schedule it in cron tab

Comment: Nice answer, right now I'm using this method and add it to cron... Need to wait it. Thanks before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont use [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)? You need to set the mail code (like mail.php) to run every 10 months, for that cron is designed.

Cron format looks like:

`minute hour day_of_month month day_of_week command_you_want_to_execute`

### Example

If you want to run a program in 15:31, day 06 in month 09, the cron will be:

`31 15 06 09 * /path/to/file.php`

### Run the Cron

Important for us to remember that php is a **deciphered language** and the php engine is it deciphers and executes our code. The software we need to run practice it is not our script, is our php engine and tell him to perform the code is written to the file. Usually the end result will look like this:

`* * * * * php -f /path/to/file.php`

### Where should i write this

Crontab file is a file of the operating system. Users do not always have access to it, but you can write the commands through the panel of the storage company.

Comment: I send it not every 10 month but 10 month after last payment made by my client.. Any solution? By the way, thanks for explanation.. very clear

Comment: Sidenote: All you needed to do was to undelete your other answer and I would've removed my -1

Comment: Leave it then. But next time, please provide actual solutions instead of links and comments. That's a sure way of getting downvoted. I will +1 because of the added effort.

Comment: In this case, BurhanÇetin gave a better answer. 
@Fred-ii- Ok, thank you! :)

Comment: @biolarnative Yes, I'm using Burhan method, but I need to open it everyday then... :( Thanks again for Your help and explanation.

Comment: @user3608809 If you need to open it every day, then CRON is what you should use because you don't need to do anything. Your code will only work if you access the file yoursel via your Web browser. It doesn't happen on its own.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, exactly! But biolarnative said that Burhan answer is better answer. I've read the wiki about cron, and I think it can't be done at my system. Or what You mean is give cron job to my file that contain Burhan method everyday?

Comment: @user3608809 You can have cron run any `.php` file you want. It's not the code that Burhan gave you that you need to run, it's the file that will do the query itself.

Comment: @user3608809 I said that because you didn't explained yourself properly. If you need to run the file every day, so yes, the best solution is cron.

Comment: @biolarnative sorry, my bad.. because my real question is sending email annually. After read cron, I guess maybe I can run a mailer everyday with cron... So I join Your answer and Sivagopal answer, maybe it's the best answer, because I need to wait it send me an email. Thank You!

Comment: It paid off eh? @biolarnative ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yep, I really liked the site (stackoverflow), while I answer questions I'm learning new things in other people's responses to other questions, a good way to improve the programming skills :)

Comment: @biolarnative You and I both. One of the best places to learn from Q&A's - this is where I basically learned 50-70% of what I now know, and still learning. Even the pros have something to learn too, the job is never completely done.

Answer (score 1):

```
$date1 = $lastpaymentdate;
$date2 = date('Y-m-d');

$ts1 = strtotime($date1);
$ts2 = strtotime($date2);

$year1 = date('Y', $ts1);
$year2 = date('Y', $ts2);

$month1 = date('m', $ts1);
$month2 = date('m', $ts2);

$diff = (($year2 - $year1) * 12) + ($month2 - $month1);
if($diff > 9){
// send mail    
}
```

Comment: And this code does... what? Please don't post code-only answers.

Comment: and where I should put mail() function? if ($diff = 10)?

Comment: its so sample. set your last payment date to $date1 and set $date2=date('Y-m-d'); the if ($diff > 9){send mail};